# How to create a 2d flat mesh from a set of profile curves

Tags: python, mesh

My goal is to use a set of curves like theese:

[image: A set of points]

Into a mesh like this, but with rounded edges and in a procedural way:

[image]

I wanna generate this curve so I set the curves shape using python to move the points around randomly and get thousands of variations of this object. And then use that to train a machine learning model.

Blender version: 2.92

Comment: Have you tried `GeometryNodes`?

Comment: Hi @Karan, thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a try, but couldn't get it to work. Even tried starting from a mesh instead of curves, no success.

Comment: Update: I download the latest version of blender (3.4.1) which have a lot of new geometry nodes and I could easily achieve this using the curve-to-mesh node. Thank you!